# jQuery counts badly height of the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've got seven div's, each with class "row", every one of them has it's own content which is hidden at the beginning, but there is also a timeline which starts with the first row div and ends on the last row div It's height is counted dynamically, depending on a row's summed up height. Code goes like this:

```
<div id="milestone_view" class="timeline">
  <div id="line" ></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

And the js code:

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$("#milestone_view").children('.row').each(function(){
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
    $(this).attr('height',$(this).height());
});
$("div#line").css({height:(totalHeight)});
alert(totalHeight);
```

I've added this line `$(this).attr('height',$(this).height());` to check each div's height.
Seems simple, but when the page is loaded I get alert with "363" and six divs have height=51, one has 57 ( little biger, it's ok ), then when I click on any div to show it's content, and again click it to hide it ( and call this function again ) I get "419" and six div's has height of 59px and one with 65px. It's like their height is badly counted initially.

I don't know if I explained it clearly, it's just a small part of an app written in kendoui, but right now this small part is not working. If that changes anything: those div's are loaded dynamically, not only their content. Their number can be other then seven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your `.row` elements have 8px margin around them. Change `height()` to `outerHeight()` to include this margin:

```
totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: If you want to include margins too: `$(this).outerHeight(true);`

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you have `padding`, `margin`, `border` or `line height` styles applying to your hidden elements only when they are displayed accounting for the difference before and after they are displayed.